# Isolated instances of Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine

I am using Microsoft Windows Azure Cloud, I have configure Virtual Machine(VM) in autoscale.

Total four 4 VM's, 3 instances created from the original Virtual machine.

Now the problem is when more than 1 instance is running,

lets say 3 instances are running - all three instances are isolated copies.

When I use my website to upload images or files, or delete them. They only get deleted from one instance, which the "load balancer" chooses. It doesn't get uploaded or deleted from the other instances.

How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

this is a classic design pattern in load-balanaced websites.  Any data that needs to be shared across multiple servers within a load-balanced web farm should be saved centrally, not on individual servers.  If you have folks uploading files, you can save them to Azure Blob Storage for example.